# Subscriber class has no public methods called on Event

Tags: android, android-fragments, greenrobot-eventbus

while using green Robot Eventbus I got an error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(2537): Caused by: de.greenrobot.event.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.example.MyActivity has no public methods called onEvent
```

Details:

I'm loading Activity which contains a fragment with 10 child fragments, rather than calling   `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);` in every nested (child) fragment I called that `register` in a parent activity of that fragment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by declaring the `onEventMainThread` method and `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);` in a same fragment (should be declared in same class)

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the onEventMainThread method :

```
    @Subscribe
public void onEventMainThread(OTPEvent event) {

}
```