# EventBus exception when proj is built - Subscriber class has no public methods called onEvent

Tags: android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

So, my app exchanges messages from/to my MainActivity to/from a background Service and I used [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to handle that. I'm registering both components with

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

on their onCreates. And I'm sending/receiving an event with:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyMessagePojo("message"));
```

and

```
public void onEvent(MyMessagePojo event) { ... }
```

Everything works well when I run the project from my AndroidStudio right to my test phone. However, when I generated the signed APK I installed the app and got a crash with the following exception:

```
Subscriber class my.package.MainActivity has no public methods called onEvent
```

Where it clearly has. I tried changing it from `onEvent` to `onEventMainThread` in my MainActivity but with no success. It's pretty frustrating since I was about to publish the app and now I can't fix this problem.

I've been through [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/79) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926859/subscriber-class-has-no-public-methods-called-on-event) but they were of no help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your ProGuard configuration is probably renaming `onEvent()`, as it thinks that it is safe to rename. Adjust your project's ProGuard configuration to keep that method intact.

Comment: Would you have any instructions/references for that? I'm not that familiar with ProGuard configurations yet

Comment: What do you mean? In the end I just turned proguard off, and it seems there's no big difference on that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is is addressed in the EventBus HOWTO docs.
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md

Use the below code to keep only the onEvent functions.

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent*(**);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped :)

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to keep this method adding the following configuration on ProGuard:

```
-keep public class my.package.MainActivity {
    public <methods>;
}
```

However, ProGuard is messing up with more stuff on my app. I can't even login to my app (and I don't know why, I just get a Network Problem alert right away). I'm seriously considering to turn it off.